# Jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'info'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using spotify's API to get this week's new releases and I'm trying to parse through the returned data to display it on the webpage using jinja2, the problem is that every time i try to run the program an error pops up saying: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'info'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'elif' or 'else' or 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.`

I tried different syntax for appending to a list in jinja2 but nothing works it just gives me the same `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag`

To better understand the data spotify returns you can use spotify's console: https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-new-releases/?country=&limit=&offset=

This is the code i wrote, help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<section class="wrapper">
    <div class="new-releases">
        <h1 id="NRH">New Releases</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="records">
            {% for record in releases['albums']['items'] %}
                {% for key, value in record.items() %}
                    {% set info = [] %}

                    {% if key == "name" %}
                        {% append value to info %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if key == "artists" %}
                        {% for k, v in value[0].items() %}
                            {% if k == "name" %}
                                {% append v to info %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if key == "external-urls" %}
                        {% for k, v in value[0].items() %}
                            {% if k == "spotify" %}
                                {% append v to info %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if key == "images" %}
                        {% for k, v in value[1].items() %}
                            {% if k == "url" %}
                                <img src="{{v}}" title="{{info[0]}}.{{info[1]}}">
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</section>
```

Comment: I've never seen this syntax: `{% append value to info %}`. I guess that is wrong.

Comment: That document says _"Because we wanted to avoid using the underlying python Language, the notation in Exponea somewhat differs from the one officially supported in Jinja. Instead of `myList.append(myValue)` you will need to use `append myValue to myList`"_. Now, I've never heard of "Exponea" before, but it seems to be a variation of Jinja with a different syntax. You should use Exponea instead of Jinja for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

change `{% append v to info %}`
to `{{ info.append(v) }}`